# matching multiple inputs with database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a self test page where php matches the input with the database and checks if the answer is right. but so far I don't know how to get it to check all the answers individually. the script i got so far only works if all the answers are wrong. How would I do this in PHP?

this is my code so far:

```
    <?php 
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pwd = "";
    $db_name = "flashcards";
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db_name)or die("cannot connect");

    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 25") or die(mysqli_error($link));
    echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'><table border='1'>";
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            echo "<tr><td value='".$rows['ID']."'>".$rows['Question']."</td><td><input type='text' name='Answer'></input></td></tr>";
        }  
    echo "</table><input type='submit' name='submit'>test</input></form>";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { 
        if ($_POST['Answer'] != $rows['Answer']) 
        {
        echo "wrong!";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "right";
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: can you explain clearly, not getting ----`I don't know how to get it to check all the answers individually` means?

Comment: answer also in same table `Questions`?

Comment: @Rajツ they are all in the same table. Also I want the answers to match the database answers and echo if the question is the same or not.

Comment: Can you please post your table structure?

Comment: @Rajツ the table name is Flashcards inside the table i have 3 rows. One is ID auto-increment int. two is Question, text. and the last one is Answer, text.

Comment: this is not gud idea to have both question and answers in same table. my suggestion is, have 2 table for question and answer(ques id should be foreign key reference) so that we can easily identify the question and their corresponding answers...

Comment: yes, but then I still need to compare the answer to the answer in the database. I tought I could use foreach but I'm not sure how to work that out. thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Raj, the layout has nothing to do with the functionality.

Comment: @RomiHalasz yeah, that was my suggestion, not a solution. thanks for notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<input type='text' name='Answer'></input>
```

The problem being that all the answer inputs have the same "name", so for each field that you answer, the value (the answer string) gets overwritten.

In order to fix this, you need to get an array of answers, like so:

```
<input type='text' name='Answer[]'></input>
```

And then, iterate trough it:

```
foreach($_POST['Answer'] as $answer)
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        { 
            if ($answer != $rows['Answer'])
            //...
```

Comment: I get an error when i try this.'warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php3\ala\index.php on line 28'

Comment: put a condition before loop starts `if(!empty($_POST['Answer'])){ //loop }`

Comment: Hi guys! I'm happy it worked. As for the warning, you should only do the checking IF the form was submitted. This means checking if the $_POST value corresponding to the submit button's name is set, like so:

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
//...

But the way Raj suggested also works! Nice one!